# Use Google maps for reverse geocoding

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, geolocation

Can I use Google maps instead of blackberry apis to do reverse geocoding?

Comment: Ok Scott,Thank you for your information..

Comment: Yea Scott, I am lookingf for reverse GeoCordinate.... I interested to use google map to find it rather than blackberry maps.And I wish to get it with out open google map,Is it possible? If there is a way,Please help..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Then, the follow-up question is [How do I read the JSON data returned by Google's API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967033/read-json-data-returned-by-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. However, you should be careful with this *Terms & Conditions* statement:

> Note: the Geocoding API may only be
>   used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   geocoding results without displaying
>   them on a map is prohibited. For
>   complete details on allowed usage,
>   consult the Maps API Terms of Service
>   License Restrictions.

More info: [Google Geocoding API Limits](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)