# Read JSON data returned by google maps

Tags: blackberry, java-me, json

In my app I use the BlackBerry API to get latitude and longitude. I would like to do reverse geocoding using Google maps by creating an http connection. How do I parse the data, and then read a specific element, such as the address?

An example URL:

> http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=9.6,73.7

Gives response:

```
{
  "name": "9.600000,76.760000",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "Kanjirappalli Elikkulam Rd, Kerala, India",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 6,
   "Country" : {
      "AdministrativeArea" : {
         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "Kerala",
         "SubAdministrativeArea" : {
            "SubAdministrativeAreaName" : "Kottayam",
            "Thoroughfare" : {
               "ThoroughfareName" : "Kanjirappalli Elikkulam Rd"
            }
         }
      },
      "CountryName" : "India",
      "CountryNameCode" : "IN"
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [JSON ME](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/) library. See [Using JSON in Java ME](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/) for examples of how to use it.

Comment: Incidentally, RIM has added this library to the native API as of 6.0.  But for previous versions, you still need to compile it in.